# jdni LDAP query to multiple LDAP URLs with multiple Base DNs

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

**My LDAP trees are as follows**

```
ad.example.com
region1.ad.example.com
region2.ad.example.com
region3.ad.example.com
```

**My LDAP servers are as follows**

```
ldap://region1.example.com:389
ldap://region2.example.com:389
```

**My Users are as follows**

Users in region1.ad.example.com have the following object properties

```
CN=user1,OU=ou1,OU=ou2,OU=ou3,DC=region1,DC=AD,DC=example,DC=com
CN=user2,OU=ou1,OU=ou2,OU=ou3,DC=region1,DC=AD,DC=example,DC=com
```

Users in region2.ad.example.com have the following object properties

```
CN=user3,OU=ou4,OU=ou5,OU=ou6,DC=region2,DC=AD,DC=example,DC=com
```

**For fetching users in region1**

```
LDAP URL: ldap://region1.example.com:389
Base DN: region1.ad.example.com
```

**For fetching users in region2**

```
LDAP URL: ldap://region2.example.com:389
Base DN: region2.ad.example.com
```

Individually both work fine when connecting to a region and searching for a user in that region.

I want to check if there is a way to connect to multiple LDAP URLs and multiple Base DN like above and search for a user with a single search

I tried to search by looping through each region url and base dn and they work fine. Is there a way to search without looping through?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Microsoft Active Directory?

Comment: Yes, using MS active directory

Comment: Why not search for users from a base of DC=AD,DC=example,DC=com

Comment: ad.example.com is another ldap tree. Tried that option too, but not able to search the user

Comment: So they are part of the same Forest? Then do LDAP search on port 3289 (Global catalog) with a base of DC=AD,DC=example,DC=com

Comment: ad.example.com,  region1.example.com, region2.example.com are all different ldap trees. Anyways I tried with a base search of DC=AD,DC=example,DC=com, but no luck finding user in another tree

Comment: So they are part of the same Forest?       Did you try:  do LDAP search on port 3289 (Global catalog) with a base of DC=AD,DC=example,DC=com